# Combining both Bevel Tools in to One (Edge Bevel and Vertex Bevel)

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

Currently in Blender you have two bevels:

-Ctrl+B (for edges and faces)

-Ctrl+Shift+B (for vertices).

I was trying to create an operator that will identify what mode you're in and activate the appropriate Bevel Tool.

I bound this script to a hotkey and it actually works, **HOWEVER**, it applies the bevel instantly without giving me the interactive mouse drag for *offset* and scroll wheel to change *segments*.

**QUESTION:
How can I activate the interactive version of the bevel tools from the operator script?**

My current script:

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    #for ob in context.scene.objects:
        #print(ob)
    toolSettings = bpy.context.tool_settings
    if toolSettings.mesh_select_mode[1]:
        print('Edge Mode Active')
        bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.48369, offset_pct=0, vertex_only=False)
    elif toolSettings.mesh_select_mode[0]:
        print('Vertex Mode Active')
        bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.537019, offset_pct=0, vertex_only=True)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some outside help I found the commands I needed to activate the interactive version of the bevel tool from the script.

It's wrapped around an operator so it can easily be mapped to the "B" key for example.

```
import bpy

def main(context):

    toolSettings = bpy.context.tool_settings

    #Are we in Vertex Mode?
    if toolSettings.mesh_select_mode[0]:
        bpy.ops.mesh.bevel('INVOKE_DEFAULT', vertex_only=True)

    #Any other Mode...
    else:
        bpy.ops.mesh.bevel('INVOKE_DEFAULT')


class SmartBevel(bpy.types.Operator):

    """

    [Smart Bevel]

    Description:
    You no longer need 2 separate hotkeys to bevel vertices or edges/faces.
    Simply map the command to something like the "B" key under "3D View / Mesh / Mesh (Global) / Add New Keymap".

    Command:
    arc.smart_bevel

    (www.armoredColony.com)

    """

    bl_idname = "arc.smart_bevel"
    bl_label = "Smart Bevel (ARC)"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SmartBevel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SmartBevel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```